# Installation of autoware.ai

Tags: ubuntu, ros

i was trying to install autoware.ai in ubuntu18.04.5 with ros-melodic .. but i m facing sum issues while installing it .. the runtime manager is not getting launch ..i hv used the commands as below to run the autoware:
$ cd autoware/ros

$ source install/setup.bash

$ ./run
when the run the last run command i m getting a message like :

```
 # Option “--command” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.

 # Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.

 # Option “--command” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.

 # Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

so could anyone help me out with this .. thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have followed all dependencies steps.

```
$ sudo apt update    
$ sudo apt install -y python-catkin-pkg python-rosdep ros-$ROS_DISTRO-catkin    
$ sudo apt install -y python3-pip python3-colcon-common-extensions python3-setuptools python3-vcstool    
$ pip3 install -U setuptools    
$ git checkout 1.11.1    
$ rosdep update    
$ rosdep install -y --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro $ROS_DISTRO
```

Then, for ros melodic installation follow the below link:

http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu